# How do I decrypt files on my SD card that I encrypted

Tags: encryption

I recently encrypted my sd card on my kyocera hydro air c6745 and it won't allow me to decrypt. I want to download music but it obviously won't allow me to do that either

Comment: What did you use to encrypt it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Settings app, and select Lock screen and Security.
2. Scroll to the bottom and select Decrypt SD Card.
3. Tap Decrypt SD card to begin the process.
4. Enter your lock screen pin, pattern or password.
5. Wait for the decryption to finish - you can keep an eye on the progress in the notification panel. Make sure to keep the device charged during the process as it can take some time.

**Reboot Your Phone and try again if not works.**